# Optional Parameters in angularJS $http get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slim

I've built an API using Slim Framework.
One of my routes in Slim accept optional parameters.
Is there any way I can do this using angularjs `$http.get`. How can I set optional parameters in my request.

Below is my code;

```
$scope.getRestaurant = function () {
    return $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: "http://api.example.co.uk/web/restaurant/details/" + $scope.id + "/" + $scope.u,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
        return response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        return [];
    });
}
```

As you can see I have `$scope.id` and `$scope.u`. I will like `$scope.u` to be optional. At the moment it is always passed even when it is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it to the url if it's truthy.

```
var baseUrl = 'http://api.example.co.uk/web/restaurant/details/' + $scope.id;
if($scope.u) baseUrl += '/' + $scope.u;
```

Answer (score 0):

//edited

You can use a ternary test like bellow:

```
 $scope.getRestaurant = function () {
     return $http({
         method: 'get',
         url: "http://api.example.co.uk/web/restaurant/details/" + $scope.id + 
             ( $scope.u != null ) ? "/"+$scope.u : ""   ,
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
     }).then(function successCallback(response) {
         // this callback will be called asynchronously
         // when the response is available
         return response.data;
     }, function errorCallback(response) {
         // called asynchronously if an error occurs
         // or server returns response with an error status.
         return [];
     });
 }
```

or create your url before you make your return

```
 $scope.getRestaurant = function () {

     var url  = "http://api.example.co.uk/web/restaurant/details/" + $scope.id +
             ( $scope.u != null ) ? "/"  +$scope.u : "" ;

     return $http({
         method: 'get',
         url: url,
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
     }).then(function successCallback(response) {
         // this callback will be called asynchronously
         // when the response is available
         return response.data;
     }, function errorCallback(response) {
         // called asynchronously if an error occurs
         // or server returns response with an error status.
         return [];
     });
 }
```

Comment: I need to check if `$scope.u` is null or not, your code seams to be checking `$scope.id`